# A question about verbs in time clauses

Tags: present-perfect, sequence-of-tenses, future-perfect

1. I'll have finished the letter by the time you come back.
2. I'll have finished the letter by the time you have come back.

Do these sentences mean the same? If so, why?

Comment: Helium, on this site, people asking questions are required to demonstrate that they've already done some research. Have you looked for examples of both? You can use Ngram searches like [this one](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=by+the+time+you+come%2Cby+the+time+you%27ve+come&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cby%20the%20time%20you%20come%3B%2Cc0) to give you a strong idea of which is better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first example makes sense, saying the letter will be done at the moment of your return.

*by the time you have come back* means when your return is in the past, but that starts one instant after your return, so it doesn't add anything to the meaning. You should avoid using a more complex tense expression than what you need.

Comment: "by the time you have come back means when your return is in the past, but that starts one instant after your return, so it doesn't add anything to the meaning." I don't quite understand what you mean. Could reformulate it, please?

Comment: If I say *you have come back*, that is only true if your return is in the past. It's *present perfect*. The word *perfect* means that it is a completed action.

Comment: Thank you, I see it now. So the second sentence is meaningless because the main clause refers to the future, right? And one more question if I may. 'but that starts one instant after your return' What did you mean by 'that'?

Comment: The second sentence doesn't make sense, because in "by the time X", that time X must be a single point in time. The time denoted by "you have come back" is all the time starting with your return and continuing into the infinite future. If you have come back by 2 PM, it's still true a million years later that you have come back. So,the perfect tense means a span of time, but the phrase "by the time X" must refer to a single moment in time.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my questions!